SSL Module Unavailable in Python: Configuring TLS/SSL for pip on Rocky Linux 9
The issue arises when attempting to install flask-oidc==1.4.0 and okta==0.0.4 using pip on a Rocky Linux 9 server. The error stems from the absence or misconfiguration of the SSL module within Python, preventing pip from securely connecting to HTTPS URLs such as PyPI. This SSL module is crucial for establishing secure connections, and its absence causes pip to fail when fetching package metadata or attempting to install packages, resulting in the SSL-related errors encountered during installation attempts.
'''
pip install flask-oidc==1.4.0 okta==0.0.4
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask-oidc/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask-oidc/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask-oidc/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask-oidc/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/flask-oidc/
Could not fetch URL
https://pypi.org/simple/flask-oidc/:
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/flask-oidc/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask-oidc==1.4.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask-oidc==1.4.0
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL
https://pypi.org/simple/pip/:
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
(venv) [root@test-ds bin]# pip install flask-oidc okta
'''

The issue arises when attempting to install flask-oidc==1.4.0 and okta==0.0.4 using pip on a Rocky Linux 9 server. The error stems from the absence or misconfiguration of the SSL module within Python, preventing pip from securely connecting to HTTPS URLs such as PyPI. This SSL module is crucial for establishing secure connections, and its absence causes pip to fail when fetching package metadata or attempting to install packages, resulting in the SSL-related errors encountered during installation attempts.


Would you like to ask a question? If you just want software support for installing something, consider contacting the vendor. In any case, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Yes, while installing the pip install flask-oidc==1.4.0 okta==0.0.4, I got this error There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/flask-oidc/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask-oidc==1.4.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for flask-oidc==1.4.0

Did you install the python Openssl module as suggested by the error message?

yes I have installed
